# MongoDB - Group and Find Top N with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider this test collection, in which an airport is identified by `AirportID`:

```
[
    { AirportID:"1001", delayMinutes :"15.0" },
    { AirportID:"1004", delayMinutes :"3.0" },
    { AirportID:"1001", delayMinutes :"20.0" },
    { AirportID:"1002", delayMinutes :"6.0" },
    { AirportID:"1002", delayMinutes :"25.0" },
    { AirportID:"1004", delayMinutes :"55.0" },
]
```

I want to group it together and list the top 2 from that list with the condition that `$delayMinutes` is greater than "10.0".
I want to group it together and list the top 2 from that list.

Code I have tried:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$AirportID",
      delayMinutes: {
        $sum: {
          "$toDouble": "$delayMinutes"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      delayMinutes: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

Comment: delayMinutes need to be greater than 10 first and group together by sum, I tried some ways but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the requirement is clarified**,

You need to filter the document **first** with `delayMinutes` field greater than (`$gt`) 10.

Make sure you convert the `delayMinutes` to `double` before comparing.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            "$toDouble": "$delayMinutes"
          },
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$AirportID",
      delayMinutes: {
        $sum: {
          "$toDouble": "$delayMinutes"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      delayMinutes: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QdpuqlEneHk)

---

And you can update the `delayMinutes` field to double with the `$set` stage. As it is redundant in the `$match` and `$group` stages.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      delayMinutes: {
        "$toDouble": "$delayMinutes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$delayMinutes",
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$AirportID",
      delayMinutes: {
        $sum: "$delayMinutes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      delayMinutes: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (with `$set`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uFxowHVn3gP)

Comment: I tried this but it seems that it didn't filter out

Comment: Did you see the output with `delayMinutes` less than 10?

Comment: yes it's still there

Comment: It need to be greater than 10 first and group it together by sum

Comment: Hi, done update the answer. Thanks for clarify.